# How to use grep to get mercurial changeset id?

Tags: macos, grep

So from the below I want to fetch the `6e4a01192927`part in my bash script

```
$ hg log -l1
changeset:   1775:6e4a01192927
branch:      xxx
tag:         tip
parent:      1772:7892c965215d
parent:      1774:5a9a3e060869
user:        Firstname Lastname <someone@something.xyz>
date:        Thu Jan 25 09:55:35 2018 +0000
summary:     Merged in fix/something (pull request #85)
```

I am on Mac, El Capitan so it seems I am very limited in the ways I can grep it..

For example `grep -oP` isn't supported..

I have gotten this far but then hit a brick wall..

```
$ hg log -l1 | sed -n 1p # fetching first line only
changeset:   1775:6e4a01192927
```

Comment: You can try `awk -F: '/changeset/{print $NF}'`

Comment: @PS. it returns "06f9c701bf33
     Added tag 1.0.2 for changeset e1a258c7c01b"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are absolutely sure of the search string use `Awk` to match the first field and print the field next to it

```
hg log -l1 | awk -F: '$1=="changeset"{print $NF}'
```

Here `$1` and `$NF` represent the first and the last fields split by the de-limiter `:`

Also a `bash` trick do it would be to read the first line from the command and use paramter expansion syntax

```
read -r firstLine < <(hg log -l1)
echo "${firstLine##*:}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Mercurial has many ways to give you just the id of the most recent (or any) commit.

```
$ hg id -i -r .
68e111c5bd42
```

or using log:

```
$ hg log -l 1 --template '{node|short}'
68e111c5bd42
```

fewer processes spawned and more portable.

Comment: you must be using some plugin or newer or older version of mercurial, this didn't work for me at least.. not using mercurial anymore so I can't say which version I had :P